# Nativescript Gridlayout css pseudo class :highlighted

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

I have a grid layout like this

```
     <GridLayout   class="testMe" dock="left" top="0" width="50%" height="100%" style="background-color:green;clip-path: circle(200% at 100% 100% 0% 0%);margin: 0 1 0 0;">
          <Label class="testMe" text = "Left parking" textWrap="true" />

          <image src="res://icon" class="testMe" style="vertical-align:bottom;horizontal-align: right;margin-bottom:20;margin-right:20;width:40"/>
      </GridLayout>
```

I am trying to add a css pseudo class like this

```
.testMe:highlighted {
   background-color:cyan;
}
```

I don't see that high light on click. Does it work or am I missing anything here?

Comment: The `highlighted ` pseudo class will be supported for the button with version 2.4. Related with issue - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/50#issuecomment-257864208 . You could also review this plugin `nativescript-theme-core`, which could help you to style your app. For further help you could review the article here - http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme .

Comment: @NikolayTsonev I am using version 2.4, so in that case the highlight does not work on any layout clicks. If I understood it correctly.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev For the same code on Gridlayout, I am using clip-path circle to show 1/4 portion of it. I have added tap event on grid layout. If I click all the way on gridlayout the event is fired, for me  the click event should be fired just in the place where the clip path is seen not on full grid. Is that possible?